# Android - Image cache using volley

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I'm using volley for my all network connections. For image cache as well we're using volley to download images.

We're using below class to cache images -

```
public class BitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
        return cacheSize;
    }

    public BitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public BitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

But issue is that when we clear app form app stack (kill app), volley downloading same images again. I wanted to do it like till then we clear image cache, it should stored in app file location (don't want to use sdcard storage).
The volley library we're using which don't have DiscLruCache. I've heard about DiscLruCache many posts, but don't know that how we could use as I've restriction to not to change volley library which we're already using.

Comment: U can also use the other library like Universal or Glide to maintain the cache

Answer (score 0):

Meybe this example from Google I/O 2013 will help You

https://github.com/rdrobinson3/VolleyImageCacheExample